# QT passing data between threads, worker function doWork() doesn't start

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, raspberry-pi, qthread

I'm new in Qt and I have a problem. I'm trying send data from worker thread using signal dataReady to slot in mainwindow updateData.
My problem is that my doWork function doesn't starts and don't emit signal.
The project is being develop on RPi 4B in Qt5.
What I have done wrong, because I tried many examples from internet and nothing is changing.

worker header file

```
class MyThreadWorker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    int correct;

public:
      MyThreadWorker();

private:
    Adafruit_BNO055 * imu_first;
    QTimer * timer;

signals:
    void dataReady(float x, float y, float z, int correct);

public slots:
    void doWork();
    void start();
};
```

worker source file

```
void MyThreadWorker::start()
{
    imu_first = new Adafruit_BNO055;
    imu_first->imu_initialization();

    timer = new QTimer();
    timer->start(1000);
    qDebug() << QString("start work in time");
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(doWork()));
}

void MyThreadWorker::doWork()
{
    imu_first->sig_bno_handler();
    gpioSleep(0, 0, 1000);
    imu_first->savevector();
    //zapis danych
    x=imu_first->myStruct.x;
    y=imu_first->myStruct.y;
    z=imu_first->myStruct.z;
    correct=imu_first->init_correct;
    qDebug()<<"Dane: " << x;

    emit dataReady(x, y, z, correct);
}
```

and mainwindow source code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //imuobiekt = new Adafruit_BNO055();
    auto thread = new QThread;
    auto worker = new MyThreadWorker();
     
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker , SLOT(start()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(dataReady(float,float,float,int)), this, SLOT(updateData(float,float,float,int)));

    worker->start();

    //setting the temperature sliders range
    ui->slider1->setMinimum(10);
    ui->slider2->setMinimum(10);
    ui->slider1->setMaximum(50);
    ui->slider2->setMaximum(50);

    //imuobiekt->imu_initialization();
    gpioSleep(0, 0, 2000);
}

void MainWindow::updateData(float x, float y, float z, int correct)
{
  //procces data in mainwindow
}
```

I really want to make it work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What does `gpioSleep(0, 0, 2000);` do?

Comment: You don't start the thread so started() is never emitted. And why does MyThreadWorker derive from QThread for no reason?

Comment: Thank you cherlic I didn't saw that mistake i changed worker->start to thread->start and it works great. It's obviouse but i my mind didn't saw that. MyThreadWorker is old thread class and i forgot to change QThread to QObject.

Comment: Topic is closed thank you.